# Python exit code in SciTE -1073741819

Tags: python, audio, system, scite

A small piece of python code breaks/exits with -1073741819 within SciTE.

Is there a way to attach a system sound or anything to alert me on exit. 
So far, its a silent break.

Answer (score 1):

Scite has way of configuring various aspects of the editor via properties file.

Some of the properties of interest to you configuring following events for system sound:

```
warning.findwrapped
warning.notfound
warning.wrongfile
warning.executeok
warning.executeko
warning.nootherbookmark
```

See Scite doc: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html